# Can I install Android 2.2 or 2.3 on a Samsung Omnia 2?

Tags: operating-system

I would like to install android 2.3 or 2.2 in my Samsung Omnia 2.

Could you tell me how should I do?

Comment: is that even possible?

Answer (score 3):

I think the Omnia 2 is a Windows phone normally? So it is very unlikely to have an official Android release for it. You're going to have to wait for someone to put together an unofficial release and hope that it's possible for them to get or write all the drivers, etc.

It looks like there was an attempt by some of the XDA people to port Android to the i8000 Omnia 2 back in February, but they hit problems because there were n[o Android devices using the i8000's ARM1176 S3C6410 CPU](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=625136&page=3) at the time.

Your best bet is going to be to keep an eye on (and offer to help out at) the [Omnia II ROM Development](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=570) sub-forum of [XDA's Samsung Omnia II forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=566).

Answer (score 2):

There is an **Omnia II Android Development forum** on XDA developers now. Current threads providing installable packages and instructions for Android 2.2 Froyo are:

- [Omnia II - Automated Installation - Android 2.2](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1097005) by ChrisMitsis, Beta 2 version as of 5 June 2011.
- [froyo bundle and how to install (updated)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1066313) by ritchietos, updated as of 17 May 2011.

Answer (score 0):

There is a beta release for Android 2.2 for your Omnia 2: http://o2droid.phj.hu/index_en.php